# Eclipse WTP shows "Fragment was not found at expected path" for included file from another maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp, eclipse-wtp, web-fragment

I have a simple maven web project composed of two modules (full source code at https://github.com/0xfthul/bug):

- bug-fragment: a web fragment project
- bug-war: a war that tries to include one file from the fragment in `index.jsp`

Eclipse is showing the following error

```
Fragment "/included.jspf" was not found at expected path /bug-war/src/main/webapp/included.jspf
```

[screenshot of my eclipse screen, showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpPAX.png)

When I run this project in wildfly it runs without errors.
If I create a similar project without using maven, eclipse shows no error.

While inspecting the error, I've found the following bug report (2013):
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398698
The projects available at the bug report are working fine.

Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)  Build id: 20190917-1200

The project structure:

```
bug
├── bug-fragment
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── META-INF
│                   ├── resources
│                   │   └── included.jspf
│                   └── web-fragment.xml
├── bug-war
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── webapp
│               ├── WEB-INF
│               │   └── web.xml
│               └── index.jsp
└── pom.xml
```

This is content of the `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file from the bug-war project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="bug-war-1.0">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
        <dependent-module archiveName="bug-fragment-1.0.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/bug-fragment/bug-fragment">
            <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
        <property name="context-root" value="bug-war"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/bug-war/target/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

Comment: Does Eclipse know that these two projects are related, like on the Deployment Assembly property page of the main war project? In the linked bug's sample projects, BugDemo1/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component shows that it's been wired together there. Ideally, the m2e-wtp plug-in or the standard m2e behavior would have linked the two together for you when you're dealing purely with Maven projects.

Comment: Yes, the bug-war project points to bug-fragment in the Deployment Assembly page. I've checked also the Project References property page. The bug-fragment was not selected, but selecting it did nothing and the error continue to appear.

Comment: If you edit the `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file in the fragment project, you should see the attribute `tag="defaultRootSource"` attached to `wb-resource` tag generated for a nonexistant `src/main/java` folder. Moving the attribute to the tag for the folder you have works as a workaround, as long as you revalidate the main web app after.

Comment: Could you open a bug report for this?

Comment: After applying the suggested workaround, eclipse stopped showing the include error. Filed a bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563352
Thanks for your support Nitin!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Expect it fixed on the June release, 2020-06.